# monitor kubernetes cluster and its all service, nodes and pods from separate prometheus server

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

My scenarios is like below

There is one prometheus server and i want to monitor my devops servers, dev deployment (which is a kubernetes cluster with 10 pods), qa deployment and prod deployment.

I want to monitor all those deployments and devops servers by central prometheus server.

I have seen couple of articles in this context. but they all refer setup prometheus on kubernetes cluster.

Looking help on how to configure k8s clusters on separate prometheus server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on question on Prometheus [Github](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/issues/815) and it's documentation, the only optimal way to get data from several K8s cluster is to use [Federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/).

You will have several Prometheus servers anyway (not only because of storing data, but also because, as example, processing [custom resource](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/api-extension/custom-resources/) which used for define check, see [design document](https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/design.md) about how it works), but in Federation mode it is possible to use it's data together.

So, you can configure, as example, [Hierarchical Federation](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/#hierarchical-federation) of Prometheus. In that mode you can use your separate Prometheus as a higher-level server, which will collect data from servers on the cluster.

You can configure you server for get metrics from `/federate` endpoint of your Prometheus servers working on K8s clusters.

From [article](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/federation/#configuring-federation):

```
- job_name: 'federate'
  scrape_interval: 15s

  honor_labels: true
  metrics_path: '/federate'

  params:
    'match[]':
      - '{job="prometheus"}'
      - '{__name__=~"job:.*"}'

  static_configs:
    - targets:
      - 'source-prometheus-1:9090'
      - 'source-prometheus-2:9090'
      - 'source-prometheus-3:9090'
```

Comment: I agree with your view. but I am thinking from different view. i see k8s cluster as node or group of nodes having containers deployed. how about if i install node_exporter + cadvisor + few custom scripts to check cluster , statefulset etc.. and create alert on that basis.

Comment: You can do it, but it will a bit complex to manage. Much more easy to install full Prometheus by [Helm](https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus), as example, and just concentrate all data on one server using Federation. It will save a lot of time and will provide a better result than a custom installation using your way. At least because you can use a tons of documentation and guides which covering that case. And that will work well for sure.